# Weird folders with byte name are being created

Tags: ubuntu, display

Does anyone know where they come from? They popup in a directory where I use screen, if that means anything.
Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The directory where you use what screen?

Comment: the screen command

Comment: We only know what you tell us about your problem, so we need to know EVERYTHING that surrounds this issue for you, the details. What are the arguments you're using with the screen command? Why are you running the screen command? What other aspects of your systems information will help us to understand enough to get you and answer.